# api route doesn't work in postman, return unauthorized

Tags: rest, api, postman

Really strange, I have a login route that work when hitting with broswer but not POSTMAN, I got unauthorized error. I arldy set the Etag as header in POSTMAN, what can be wrong?

Comment: what method of authentication are you using? Sometimes you'll find you need to add 'Bearer' to tokens in the Authentication header. Plus check CORS as that's another modern header that'll catch you out! `Authentication: Bearer {token};`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding Headers : 
"Accept", "application/json" and 
"Content-Type", "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

Usually REST services will be protected with authentications. Are you using `Basic Authentication`? Then you have to provide a `user name and password` in the header. If you are using Oauth2 then you have to provide a `bearer token` generated by your OAuth provider in your header.

The unauthorized error clearly says that it's related with the security credentials.